# If a paladin that used sacred weapon on a two handed weapon takes one hand off the weapon does sacred weapon dispell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, spellcasting, paladin

I realise it sounds strange but, if a paladin were to cast sacred weapon on a two handed great sword then use one hand to cast another spell would sacred weapon stop working?

I am having a discussion with my current group about the wording of sacred weapon but my DM argues that because it is a two handed weapon he has technically let go of it to cast a spell because he is holding a two handed weapon with one hand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### "If you are no longer holding or carrying this weapon, or if you fall unconscious, this effect ends."

This is the end condition for Sacred Weapon (Oath of Devotion Channel Divinity):

> If you are no longer holding or carrying this weapon, or if you fall unconscious, this effect ends.

It does not require that you be holding it *with two hands*, only that you be holding or carrying it. So you don't even have to have one hand on it. It can be sheathed on your back and the effect will remain active.

Comment: Pedantry, but for the record, back-sheathes are most likely entirely ahistorical. They’re not entirely impossible but they are impractical and there’s no solid evidence that anyone anywhere ever used one. Even greatswords were sheathed at the hip.

Comment: @KRyan You’ve never used a Greatsword of Back-Bearing (Common magic item)?

Comment: @KRyan: I always thought they were for porting swords, not for marching into battle. It would be easier to carry but not drawable directly. Not so much as a separate sheath, but the normal sheath strapped to the back along with the pack.

Comment: @Joshua Yeah, there have been suggestions that that might be more plausible. But nonetheless, as I understand things, we don’t have any actual archaeological examples of such a practice, or contemporary descriptions of it. If it happened, we don’t really have any direct evidence of it. Certainly, most people toting a large weapon somewhere were soldiers, and most of those just carried their weapons while marching. Anything _really_ cumbersome could go on a cart or something.